# documenting functions exposed by a pickle file

Tags: python, pickle

I have written an application in python that goes through several iterations and at the end it returns a couple of dataframes (the estimates of the quantities we are interested in). I am also saving the application as a single pickle file which exposes to the user all the objects and  functions that are involved in the loop and contribute to the return values. If a user wants to get a better insight and would like to interrogate particular functions or properties of the objects involved he/she could do

```
import pickle
import pandas as pd

pkl = pd.read_pickle('pickle_file.pickle')
pkl.course.student_names
```

and that would return a list of names
or

```
pkl.course.calc_avg([2020, 2021, 2022, 2023]
```

that returns the average of the markings for these years.

My question is how do I document that please? I mean how on earth the user would know that there is an attribute called `student_names` of the object `course` or that there is a function called `calc_avg`. Adding docstrings will help especially with functions since `help(pkl.course.calc_avg)` will print the docstring but the user should know that there is such a function at first place....

Am I doing it wrong from the very beginning maybe? I shouldnt have a pickle file, but what are the alternatives?

Comment: put the pickle in a jar (decorator) and add a label with the description?

Comment: apologies for my ignorance but how these two come together? Jar is the java package, decorator is the python function that modifies another function. Could you please elaborate a bit more? Thanks

Comment: sorry, misunderstanding. jar <-> physical container to pickle

Comment: but also without decorators should work: make a dictionary `descriptions = {"file_name1": "string_description1", ...}` and ```def read_pickle(pickle_file):
    print(descriptions[pickle_file])
    return pd.read_pickle(pickle_file)```

Comment: thats helpful, yes. thnx!